# Sync with electrical wall outlet

Tags: synchronization

I have two ac souces one being the electrical wall outlet and the othee being an inverter that will go to zero volts, and  both at 60hz.  How do I sync the inverter to the wall outlet?

Comment: That is only going to happen if the inverter has a way to dynamically adjust its phase.

Comment: Matching  Phasor differences requires detection and control of both rms amplitude and phase.  Phase locking is easy with a PLL.

Comment: Why do you need to sync them? If you explain your requirements, we can better respond to your question.

Comment: On the plus side, if the inverter can't dynamically adjust its phase, it will at least dramatically adjust it as it explodes when it loses the battle with the mains.

Comment: I asked a very similar question to several UPS manufacturers, will the output sine wave stay in sync with the input from the grid as long as it’s available. No one could answer.

Comment: Google images "Grid tied inverter". It's not a DIY project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have two ac souces (sic) one being the electrical wall outlet and the othee (sic) being an inverter that will go to zero volts, ...

I don't know what "will go to zero volts" means but read on ...

> ... and both at 60hz.

That will be 60 Hz nominal. The mains frequency will drift and so will the inverter.

How do I sync the inverter to the wall outlet?

If it doesn't have sync built in then you can't. The inverter will quickly be a permanent 0 V output.

Even if you could there is more to it than just connecting them up. Protection is required to prevent the inverter feeding out to the grid in the event of a power cut. You would be trying to power the neighbourhood and risk electricuting a lineman trying to repair a line.

Don't try it.